# Why would having multiple nameservers in resolv.conf cause nslookup to fail, but a single entry work?

Tags: 12.04, dns, resolv.conf

I have a resolv.conf on ubuntu 12.04 that looks like this (IP addresses have been changed to nonsense):

```
search internal.mydomain.com
nameserver 205.169.169.193
```

That nameserver is not authoritative for `mydomain.com`, but does contain valid records for `internal.mydomain.com`. I can issue both `host` and `nslookup` queries with this resolv.conf without issue:

```
$ host myserver
myserver.internal.mydomain.com has address 10.1.1.3

$ nslookup myserver
Server:         205.169.169.193
Address:        205.169.169.193

Name:   myserver.internal.mydomain.com
Address: 10.1.1.3
```

Everything works great, but that nameserver lives in AWS's [Route53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) can't recurse, so it can't resolve, say, `google.com`.

So I added another nameserver. Specifically, the stock AWS nameserver used by my ubuntu image on instantiation. I know it works just fine:

```
search internal.mydomain.com
nameserver 205.169.169.193
nameserver 172.152.152.112
```

Now, when I run `nslookup`, it queries the first nameserver, as I'd expect, but fails to find the record, moving onto the 172.* server:

```
$ nslookup myserver
;; Got recursion not available from 205.169.169.193, trying next server
;; Got recursion not available from 205.169.169.193, trying next server
Server:         172.152.152.112
Address:        172.152.152.112#53

** server can't find myserver: NXDOMAIN
```

I'm puzzled. Why does resolv.conf behave correctly when I have a single nameserver record, but incorrectly when I have more than one?

Notably this works as I'd expect it on Amazon's linux, `v3.4.73-64.112.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-31003)`. Is this a bug in ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: What does `host myserver` do in the second case?